# IntelliJ doesn't show stacktrace

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm writing a Java app with Gradle in IntelliJ CE. I am trying to debug, but every time the code gives any exception, the only text in the console is:

```
Execution failed for task ':Main.main()'.
> Process 'command 'F:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019/jbr/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

If I step through the code, I can see the exception in the console when it's thrown. But once the whole code execution ends, the exception disappears and I see only the message from above. (screenshot attached). [image: screenshot]

Any idea how I can fix this problem and be able to see the error message?

Comment: In that tree view on the left, select the root item.

Comment: Can you make this a proper answer so that others see a solution was contributed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that tree view on the left, select the root item.

Comment: of course it is that simple! Thank you!

Comment: it's simple, but it sucks because you need to ctrl+F then error